# GRAPHVIZ: Force node to top of page

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am using graphviz, however i woudl like to force the node "This on top" to the top of the page, and not side on. This is the graph:

[image]

This is the code:

```py
g= Digraph('trial', filename='trial.gv')
g.attr(compound='true', rankdir="TB" )

with g.subgraph() as s:
  s.attr(rank='max')
  s.node('This on top ')
  s.edge('this right under', "Fabrication")

with g.subgraph(name='cluster0') as c:
    c.node("This")

    c.node("that")
    c.node("and this on the same level")
g.edge("this right under","that", lhead="cluster0" )
g.edge("that","This on top ", ltail="cluster0" )

g
```

Is there a command to make sure that Nodes are displayed in the TOP/Bottom order i wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that setting `rank='max'` is forcing everything in the first subgraph to go to the maximum rank, which is the lowest rank. You might have meant to set `rank='min'` which would place the items in the subgraph at the highest rank, but that still wouldn't create the arrangement you want.

Instead, you can use an invisible edge by setting `style = 'invis'` when creating the edge to force "This on top" to come before "this right under".

```
from graphviz import Digraph

g= Digraph('trial', filename='trial.gv')
g.attr(compound='true', rankdir="TB" )

with g.subgraph() as s:
  # s.attr(rank='min') # you don't need this line
  s.node('This on top ')
  s.edge('This on top ', 'this right under', style='invis') # add this invisible edge
  s.edge('this right under', "Fabrication")

with g.subgraph(name='cluster0') as c:
    c.node("This")

    c.node("that")
    c.node("and this on the same level")
g.edge("this right under", "that", lhead="cluster0" )
g.edge("that", "This on top ", ltail="cluster0", constraint="false" )

g
```

Which produces:
[image: Graph showing nodes stacked]